# PHP/MySQL - Issue with the order of html/MySQL combined output

Tags: php, html, mysql, position

I'm experiencing an issue with my file output elements being misplaced.

Here's what i get at the moment (wrong order): [image: wrong order]

And the numbers here are the order i want:
[image: right order]

As far as I'm concerned the code is fine for this kind of positioning, what may be a possible cause of this issue?

```
<div class="page-leaderboard">

    <div class="text layout1">   // #1
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <h1>Najlepsi menedżerzy </h1><h1>poprzedniej kolejki</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="leaderboard-content"><? echo $top3show; ?>   // #2

        <h2 class="opacity-appear">TOP <gold>100</gold></h2>   // #3

        <h4 class="from-top-appear">Twoja aktualna pozycja:
            <gold>
                <? echo $userrealposition; ?>
            .</gold>
        </h4>   // #4

        <table class="opacity-appear top-100">   // #5
            <caption>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>
                        <svg class="table-icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                            <use xlink:href="#login-icon"></use>
                        </svg>
                        <p>Imię i nazwisko menedżera</p>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <svg class="table-icon team" viewBox="0 0 100 79">
                            <use xlink:href="#_team-icon"></use>
                        </svg>
                        <p>Nazwa drużyny</p>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <svg class='table-icon points' viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
                            <use xlink:href='#_points-icon'></use>
                        </svg>
                        <p>Doświadczenie<br><small>(ilość rozegranych kolejek)</small></p>
                    </th>
                    <th><p>Zwycięstwa w kolejkach</p></th>
                    <th>
                        <svg class="table-icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100" alt="Twój budżet">
                            <use xlink:href="#_dollar2-icon"></use>
                        </svg>
                        <p>Obecny niewykorzystany budżet</p>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </caption>
            <? echo "<tr><td class='rankposition'><p>$i</p></td><td><p>$name $secname</p></td><td><p>$teamname</p></td><td><p>$experience</p></td><td><p>$leagueswon</p></td><td><p>$mils mln</p></td></tr>";
            } ?>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

Also, as requested the live preview of this under "Ranking" button on the left: http://d0man94.ayz.pl/fantasynfl/modules/game/tester.php

Comment: We'd need to see your CSS too.

Comment: What would make the elements show in an order other than the order in which they are coded?

Comment: So open source code in any modern browser and modify it.

Comment: http://d0man94.ayz.pl/fantasynfl/modules/game/tester.php I've uploaded an online version to make it easier for you to check it up. Once u click on ranking on the menu on the left you'll have a live preview of this module.

Comment: @CameronRoe linked a live preview, css is viewable this way

Comment: @showdev i'd say CSS, but for me it doesn't seem this might have any impact there...

Answer (score 0):

Dont use h1 and h2 as div objects. Be sure to encapsulate values in divs, even if you dont wanna style them.

// #2

```
<div>
<h2 class="opacity-appear">TOP <gold>100</gold></h2>   // #3
</div>

<div>    
<h4 class="from-top-appear">Twoja aktualna pozycja:<gold>
    <? echo $userrealposition; ?>
.</gold></h4>   // #4
</div>
```

Check for position:absolute attributes as well ...